# Perl - Html write to PDF

Tags: html, perl, pdf

I'm trying to create PDF from HTML using [`PDF::FromHTML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF%3a%3aFromHTML) package. It works fine if I use load_file(html file). How do I change if I want to write text instead the html file. For an example:

```
use PDF::FromHTML;

my $pdf = PDF::FromHTML->new( encoding => 'utf-8' );
$pdf->load_file('source.html');
$pdf->convert;
$pdf->write_file('target.pdf');
```

it take the html from source.html and create the PDF. How to do if I want a text like this:

```
use PDF::FromHTML;
my $pdf = PDF::FromHTML->new( encoding => 'utf-8' );
$pdf->load_file('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
$pdf->convert;
$pdf->write_file('target.pdf');
```

Any references or advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39500941/4632019)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [`PDF::FromHTML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF%3a%3aFromHTML) suggests, use scalar reference to your html

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use PDF::FromHTML;

my $data = do {local $/; <DATA>};

my $pdf = PDF::FromHTML->new( encoding => 'utf-8' );
$pdf->load_file(\$data);
$pdf->convert;
$pdf->write_file('target.pdf');

# Start Fresh each time
BEGIN { unlink 'target.pdf'; }

__DATA__
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <p>From data block.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error. `cannot paste before root at C:/Perl/site/lib/PDF/FromHTML/Twig.pm line 105.
 at C:/Perl/site/lib/PDF/FromHTML.pm line 141.`

Comment: I've tried this earlier.. it just giving the same error message.. :(

Comment: @chinna_82 Two likely options.  You don't have the most recent version of a module, either `PDF::FromHTML` or `PDF::FromHTML::Twig`.  Or you're testing with data other than the most basic example demonstrated here.  If the former, time to upgrade.  If the latter, share your actual testing data.