# Turning HTML Results Page into PDF and Downloading in CGI file

Tags: perl, pdf-generation, cgi

I am working in PERL and I have an html results page that displays perfectly. I want to add a button that makes this html page a pdf that downloads onto your machine.  Below is the code that generates the html page. fileFH is generated in the CGI code.

```
sub searchResults {
my $data = shift;
my $file = "$OUTFILES/$data.html";

open(my $fileFH, '<', $file) or return "Can not find file\n";

print $cgi->header();

while (<$fileFH>) {
    print qq($_);
}
close($fileFH);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify if you need help with code or are you mostly interested in tools for converting to PDF?

Comment: You may also want to consider that html generation with CGI.pm is not recommended. https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are open to an external program/dependency for the conversion I highly recommend http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Flow:

1. Button Click
2. wkhtmltopdf is provided target URL
3. Output sent to user

You may want to cache the output as well to reduce the number of conversions.

**EDIT**
Perl already has a wrapper too.

https://metacpan.org/release/PDF-WebKit

Comment: And [PDF::WebKit](https://metacpan.org/release/PDF-WebKit) is a pretty nice Perl wrapper around that program.

Comment: @DaveCross I didn't even know that existed. You just made my life easier - thank you!

Comment: It doesn't do anything very clever. It's just a very thin wrapper around calling the external program.

Comment: unfortunately do not support flex yet. Should be fixed at 0.13 version, now is 0.12.5